# Bootstrap 3 Navbar won't collapse on mobile browsers but will in undersized desktop window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My Rails 4 site with the latest version of bootstrap will not collapse in mobile however if I open the site on desktop and shrink the window, it will collapse. Here is the code for my navbar:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">
        <a href = "/" class = "navbar-brand" style="color: white;">Earn And Learn</a>
        <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="nav_ach"><a href = "/about/achievements" style="color: white;">Achievements</a></li>
            <li id="nav_faq"><a href = "/about/faq" style="color: white;">FAQ</a></li>
            <li id="nav_test"><a href = "/about/testimonials" style="color: white;">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li id="nav_news"><a href = "/about/news" style="color: white;">In the News</a></li>
                <li id="nav_steal"><a href = "/steal/index" style=" color: white;">Steal This Idea!</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color: white;">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 71):

Dug through the github issues and it turns out we're missing this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10550

Comment: +1 - This worked for me and I was having the same exact issue. You just saved me HOURS of more frustration. It was literally killing me trying to understand why this would not work. Thank you!

Comment: wow. :\ thanks! It costed me hours too.. I guess I will never ignore meta tags anymore...

Comment: This needs to be selected as the answer! Thanks @Harry Moreno

Comment: same issue on mobiles with bootstrap v.4. (6 alpha). This trick din't help me (

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, still having the same problem. When i click the collapsed menu i can sort of see a slight space appear but no menu. What else could be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

there is missing the id of collapse

it must be

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">
        <a href = "/" class = "navbar-brand" style="color: white;">
            Earn And Learn
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target= ".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="nav_ach"><a href="/about/achievements" 
            style="color: white;">Achievements</a></li>
            <li id="nav_faq"><a href="/about/faq" 
           style="color: white;">FAQ</a></li>
            <li id="nav_test"><a href = "/about/testimonials" 
            style="color: white;">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li id="nav_news"><a href = "/about/news" style="color: white;">
                In the News</a></li>
                <li id="nav_steal"><a href = "/steal/index" 
                 style="color: white;">Steal This Idea!</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
                      style="color: white;">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer will not work as you have made the `data-target` a `class` (`.navHeaderCollapse`) - not an `id`. I will edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt standard bootstrap3. Look at the examples page to learn the syteax of bootstrap.
At bootstrap3 there are other important classes to make it collapse.
Look at the Examples or at my [page](http://nitram0598.zapto.org) to learn the basic code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta tag for providing device screen width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```