# Bootstrap 3 Navbar not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My Bootstrap Navbar isn't working on mobile phone view  (when it can't display the links). I can't click the button. After many research on Internet and StackOverflow, I tried out the solution and no one works. These are the solutions that I tried;

- Verify the `data-target` and `id`. [As here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067670/bootstrap-navbar-not-working-on-mobile) *Check*
- Add the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020603/bootstrap-3-navbar-wont-collapse-on-mobile-browsers-but-will-in-undersized-deskt) *Check*
- Add CSS `.dropdown-backdrop { position: static; }` On Stack, somewhere

Here is my navbar code;

```
<nav id="layout-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">7 Frères</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="navigationbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            {% for item in staticMenu.menuItems %}
                                    <li class="{% if item.isActive %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's not working about it? Seems fine to me.

Comment: @APAD1 I can't click on the button. I click, and it's stay "active", but don't open the menu.

Comment: I plugged your code into [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mF1Mm8fQn2) and accessed it on my phone and the menu works as expected, so if there is an issue, it's not with the code you posted.

Comment: @APAD1, Yes it work great. But not on my website. [You can access here](http://7freres.com/)

Comment: Your website is [not responding](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.7freres.com/).

Comment: Weird because it's working great for me. All is displayed. I think is because the DNS propagation. [Try here](http://vps46731.vps.ovh.ca/)

Comment: Yep, that's gotta be it. Your other link worked. It looks like you are using a stylesheet that is based on Bootstrap but not the official Bootstrap CSS. I would try including the official Bootstrap CSS and see if that resolves the issue, your custom CSS might be missing something.

Comment: I used this [one](https://github.com/Pingendo/pingendo-bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/themes/default/bootstrap.css)

Comment: Sorry, went off to lunch. The reason it's not working is because you are not including the Bootstrap JS (see answer below).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80821/discussion-between-inxdev-and-apad1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are not including the Bootstrap Javascript(necessary for using the built-in dropdown menu) on your page. Once you have included that, it should work:

```
<script tpye="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I work hundred of times with Bootstrap and I never noticed that JS wasn't include in this project. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to match the correct version of bootstrap when you import the JavaScript. I found it did not work with the latest bootstrap (5.0.2) and I also needed jQuery for it to work.