# Navbar bootstrap is not working on mobile phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Navabar is not working mobile devices, on desktopes it is ok.
https://dm-investment.com/
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAshk.png

Comment: An FYI that the menu works as expected for me on Chrome + iPhone. I wonder if it could be a cache issue for you?

Comment: Thank you. Looks now it is works on my iphone too. Cache  issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898781/bootstrap-3-navbar-not-working-on-mobile

Comment: Excellent, thanks for letting me know! Good luck with your site.